# How to know if a UITextField in iOS has blank spaces

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsstring, uitextfield

I have a UITextField where user can enter a name and save it. But, user should not be allowed  to enter blank spaces in the textFiled.

**1 - How can I find out,if user has entered two blank spaces or complete blank spaces in the textFiled**

**2 - How can i know if the textFiled is filled only with blank spaces**

***edit - It is invalid to enter only white spaces(blank spaces)***

Comment: Need clarification: is the user not allowed to enter *any* whitespace at all, or is it only invalid to enter *only* whitespace? That is, is the string `"this is a test"` valid or not?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can "trim" the text, that is remove all the whitespace at the start and end. If all that's left is an empty string, then only whitespace (or nothing) was entered.

```
NSString *rawString = [textField text];
NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
NSString *trimmed = [rawString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespace];
if ([trimmed length] == 0) {
    // Text was empty or only whitespace.
}
```

If you want to check whether there is any whitespace (anywhere in the text), you can do it like this:

```
NSRange range = [rawString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:whitespace];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    // There is whitespace.
}
```

If you want to prevent the user from entering whitespace at all, see @Hanon's solution.

Comment: Wow.. this one worked dude... fantastic. to the point answer..... u got 25 for this. 15+10..... ;) Thanku so much

Comment: DarkDust I learned from your answer.(+1) Why doesn't the trimmed string log as expected for [NSString stringWithString:@"s p a c e"] if you log it after/outside the if block?

Comment: @Maudicus: Trimming means to remove only from the start and the end. Any whitespace in the middle is preserved.

Answer (score 13):

if you really want to 'restrict' user from entering white space

you can implement the following method in UITextFieldDelegate

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range     replacementString:(NSString *)string { 

    NSString *resultingString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange: range withString: string];
    NSCharacterSet *whitespaceSet = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
    if  ([resultingString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:whitespaceSet].location == NSNotFound)      {
        return YES;
    }  else  {
        return NO;
    }
 }
```

If user enter space in the field, there is no change in the current text

Answer (score 6):

Use following lines of code

```
NSString *str_test = @"Example ";
NSCharacterSet *whitespaceSet = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
if([str_test rangeOfCharacterFromSet:whitespaceSet].location!=NSNotFound)
{
    NSLog(@"Found");
}
```

if you want to restrict user  use below code

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if([string isEqualToString:@" "])
    {
        return NO
    }
    else
    {
        return YES
    }
}
```

Comment: This will find *any* whitespace (for example also in `"A title"`). The poster wants to know if the string is *only* whitespace (for example `"     "`).

Comment: thanks for the answer narayana... i tried this approach before posting the question but found no success.... +1 for your answer too

Answer (score 3):

**UPD:** Swift 2.0 Support

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let whitespaceSet = NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()
    let range = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(whitespaceSet)
    if let _ = range {
        return false
    }
    else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a same condition not allowing user to input blank field

Here is my code and check statement

```
- (IBAction)acceptButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
if ([self textFieldBlankorNot:fullNametext]) {
        fullNametext.text=@"na";
    }
// saving value to dictionary and sending to server

}

-(BOOL)textFieldBlankorNot:(UITextField *)textfield{
    NSString *rawString = [textfield text];
    NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
    NSString *trimmed = [rawString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespace];
    if ([trimmed length] == 0)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres Swift 3 version

```
let whitespaceSet = NSCharacterSet.whitespaces
let range = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: whitespaceSet)
if let _ = range {
    return false
}
else {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift,

if you want to restrict the user, you can use `contains()`

For Example,

```
if userTextField.text!.contains(" "){
//your code here.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Hanon's answer is the pretty neat, but what I needed was to allow at least 1 white space, so based on Hanon's solution I made this one:

I declared a local variable called whitespaceCount to keep the counts of the white spaces.
Hope this helps anybody!

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range     replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{ 
    NSCharacterSet *whitespaceSet = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];

    if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:whitespaceSet].location != NSNotFound) 
    {
        whitespaceCount++;
        if (whitespaceCount > 1) 
        {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        whitespaceCount = 0;
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`.

```
- (BOOL)validateFields
 {
      NSString *temp = [textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                                                          withString:@""
                                                             options:NSLiteralSearch
                                                               range:NSMakeRange(0, textField.text.length)];

      if ([temp length] == 0) {
          // Alert view with message @"Please enter something."
          return NO;
      }
 }
```