# How to get the character which the user tapped in keypad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITextField` and i want to perform some action when user touches space and backspace buttons. how can i do that? I know that I have to use Keyboard Notifications. Can any one tell me how to get the value that which key has touched?

Answer (score 2):

You could implement textfield delegate's method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, the better solution is to use `UITextFieldDelegate` read the [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html). It contains method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` which you could use.

As for backspace detection, there are plenty of questions here on SO covering the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

NSString *resultingString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange: range withString: string];
NSCharacterSet *whitespaceSet = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];

if  ([resultingString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:whitespaceSet].location == NSNotFound)      {

 //Your Code Here

    return YES;

}  else  {

    return NO;
}}
```

**Edit:**

If you want to check whether there is any whitespace (anywhere in the text), you can do it like this:

```
NSRange range = [[textField text] rangeOfCharacterFromSet:whitespace];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
// There is whitespace.
}
```

Comment: It is working properly. But when i press space for first time `//your code here` is getting called. after that when ever i press any key it's getting called. why?

Comment: When i touch space i am calling `myfun()`. and i was tying like this aaaaaa<Space - `myfun` call>after this immediately after pressing this `myfun` is getting called again.

Comment: i cant understand what exactly you need!!

Comment: When press space i am adding a label with label.text = textField.text. But what is happening when ever i press space i can able to reate a label. the problem is that space that i have touched remains in the textfield so what ever key i press it's adding a label with empty text.

Comment: see this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238691/how-to-know-if-a-uitextfield-in-ios-has-blank-spaces