# Stop user from entering only spaces in textfield?

Tags: iphone, nsstring, uitextfield

In my app I have a textfield in which users have to enter a string from 1-25 characters. The problem I'm having is stopping them from only entering spaces. I want them to be able to use spaces but only if they have other characters (abc, 1-9, etc.). How can I stop them from only entering spaces?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know if a UITextField in iOS has blank spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238691/how-to-know-if-a-uitextfield-in-ios-has-blank-spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756256) question might help.

Just trim the whitespace off the string and then check to see if it is the empty string.

Answer (score 2):

In your view controller set delegate of UITextField to self. Then implement following method.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
replacementString:(NSString *)string {

  if([[textField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length] == 0){
      return NO;
   }

  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform a whitespace "trim" on their input and check to see if the result matches an empty string.