# Check if Swift text field contains non-whitespace

Tags: swift

This is an extension, not a duplicate, of [How to check if a text field is empty or not in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102641/how-to-check-if-a-text-field-is-empty-or-not-in-swift)

The given answer,

```
@IBAction func Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    if textField1.text != ""  {
        // textfield 1 
    }
}
```

does not work for me, i.e., the if-loop is triggered even when nothing is entered in the text field.  (I have modified it from the original because I'm looking to trigger the code only when the field contains text).

The second answer

```
@IBAction func Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    if !textField1.text.isEmpty{

    }
}
```

comes much closer, but it accepts strings like `"     "` as not empty.  I could build something myself, but is there a function that will check if a string contains something other than whitespace?

Comment: Here is the same question with solutions in Objective-C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238691/how-to-know-if-a-uitextfield-in-ios-has-blank-spaces. It should be easy to translate that to Swift.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

*This answer was last revised for Swift 5.2 and iOS 13.5 SDK.*

---

You can trim whitespace characters from your string and check if it's empty:

```swift
if !textField1.text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty {
    // string contains non-whitespace characters
}
```

You can also use `.whitespacesAndNewlines` to remove newline characters too.

Comment: Might I suggest `!str.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(whitespaceSet).isEmpty`? I _think_ `isEmpty` might be a little quicker since it's O(N).

Comment: I'd say isEmpty is or at least should be O(1) :)

Comment: how to check the docs here lets say, inside the parenthesis (in: .whitespaces).  What are the other options besides whitespaces? and when is trimmingCharacters only available?  Im learning how to use docs but I cant seem to find them unless i search them on Stackoverflow.  Please advise. thanks

Comment: @GelSisaed The documentation of `CharacterSet` along with all predefined values can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset

Answer (score 25):

Below is the extension I wrote that works nicely, especially for those that come from a .NET background:

```
extension String {
    func isEmptyOrWhitespace() -> Bool {

        if(self.isEmpty) {
            return true
        }

        return (self.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()) == "")
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `Value of type 'String' has no member 'stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet'` so it doesn't work or it's imcomplete

Answer (score 13):

## Swift 4.2

### Extension for String is empty or whitespace

```
extension String {
    func isEmptyOrWhitespace() -> Bool {
        
        // Check empty string
        if self.isEmpty {
            return true
        }
        // Trim and check empty string
        return (self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) == "")
    }
}
```

The original poster's code is checking `text` on a textfield which is optional. So he will need some code to check optional strings. So let's create a function to handle that too:

### Extension for Optional String is nil, empty or whitespace

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    func isEmptyOrWhitespace() -> Bool {
        // Check nil
        guard let this = self else { return true }
        
        // Check empty string
        if this.isEmpty {
            return true
        }
        // Trim and check empty string
        return (this.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) == "")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[akashivskyy answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27768113/5327882) in **Swift 3.0**:

```
let whitespaceSet = CharacterSet.whitespaces
if !str.trimmingCharacters(in: whitespaceSet).isEmpty {
  // string contains non-whitespace characters
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
extension StringProtocol where Index == String.Index {
    var isEmptyField: Bool {
        return trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) == ""
    }
}


if yourTextField.text.isEmptyField {
    // Field is empty
} else {
    // Field is NOT empty
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Answer in swift 4:

```
extension String {
    func isEmptyOrWhitespace() -> Bool {
        if(self.isEmpty) {
            return true
        }
        return (self.trimmingCharacters(in: NSCharacterSet.whitespaces) == "")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Answer in Swift 3.0

```
if stringValue.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces).isEmpty
{}
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer in **Swift 3.***, considers newlines, tabs

```
extension String {

    var containsNonWhitespace: Bool {
        return !self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty
    }

}
```

Comment: This question already has an accepted answer, along with another up-voted answer in Swift 3.

Answer (score 1):

Answer with a picture in case you need a demo

```
// MY FUNCTIONS
private func checkMandatoryFields(){

    //CHECK EMPTY OR SPACES ONLY FIELDS
    if let type = typeOutle.text, let name = nameOutlet.text, let address = addressOutlet.text, type.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty || name.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty || address.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty {
        print("Mandatory fields are: ")
        errorDisplay(error: "Mandatory fields are: Type, Name, Address.")
        return
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Major flaw with this code. If a single `text` property is `nil` then your check fails and acts as if there are no empty fields.

Answer (score 1):

Method

```
 func trim() -> String {
    return self.trimmingCharacters(in: NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
}
```

Use

```
if textField.text.trim().count == 0 {
    // Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: You can remove the `NSCharacterSet` from `NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines`. You should replace `if textField.text.trim().count == 0` with `if textField.text.trim().isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5.7.2 (but probably earlier) [`CharacterSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset) conforms to [`SetAlgebra`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/setalgebra).

So instead of creating a copy of the string with `trimmingCharacters(in:)` and `.whitespacesAndNewlines` it is possible to create a `CharacterSet` from the string using [`init(charactersIn:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset/3126608-init) and check that it is not a subset of `.whitespacesAndNewlines`

For example :

```swift
extension String {
    func hasOnlyCharachersIn(_ characterSet: CharacterSet) -> Bool {
        let charactersInSelf = CharacterSet(charactersIn: self)
        return charactersInSelf.isSubset(of: characterSet)
    }
    
    var hasNonWhitespaceCharacters: Bool {
        !hasOnlyCharachersIn(.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }
}
```

produces in a playground:

```swift
var testString = ""
testString.hasNonWhitespaceCharacters // false

testString = " "
testString.hasNonWhitespaceCharacters // false

testString = "\t"
testString.hasNonWhitespaceCharacters // false

testString = " \t\n"
testString.hasNonWhitespaceCharacters // false

testString = "\n"
testString.hasNonWhitespaceCharacters // false

testString = "foo"
testString.hasNonWhitespaceCharacters // true

testString = "foo bar"
testString.hasNonWhitespaceCharacters // true

testString = "foo\tbar"
testString.hasNonWhitespaceCharacters // true

testString = "foo bar\tbaz\n"
testString.hasNonWhitespaceCharacters // true
```

Answer (score -1):

swift 4.2

```
@IBAction func checkSendButton(_ sender: UITextField) {
    if((sender.text?.count)! > 0 && !(sender.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)).isEmpty){
        self.sendButton.isEnabled = true
    }
    else{
        self.sendButton.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 5.8**

Probably the cleanest solution:

```
extension String {
    func isEmptyOrWhitespace() -> Bool {
        return self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty
    }
}
```