# Ensure UITextField isn't ONLY full of spaces

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, null, uitextfield

I have an iOS app which has a UITextField where the user can enter in a name. I want to make sure that they user doesn't just enter a bunch of spaces and then clicks save.

Accepted as valid:

> blah blah blah with spaces

Not accepted as valid

> *only spaces*

In other words I don't care if the user adds a name with some blank spaces, what I don't want is if the user presses the space bar a few times and then saves the name.

I have thought of performing this check:

```
if ((nameField == nil) || ([nameField isEqualToString:@" "])) {
   // Not valid....
}

else {
   // Valid...
}
```

You can see that in my if statement, I am checking for @" ". That checks to make sure the user hasn't just enter a empty string with a space. But thats only for one space, if the user enters space twice and saves it, then the if statement still thinks its valid. So how do I scale this up?

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Comment: Check this post: _http://stackoverflow.com/q/8238691/4227915_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trim all white spaces like this

```
text = [text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

and if it was all spaces then `text` will be empty string and you can check

```
if (text.length == 0)
{
// not acceptable
}
else
{
//valid
}
```

Comment: Clever idea, I like it thanks :)

Comment: you are welcome, accept this answer if it helped

Comment: Yep just accepted it :)